# R package for smooth transition regression models

Tags: r, regression, time-series, nonlinear-regression

Is there a R package that I can use to specify Smooth Transition Models. I'm looking specifically for something that allows me to specify a TAR model for a given time series.

In 2008, a package, [RSTAR](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Balcilar.pdf), was presented in the R User Conference by Mehmet Balcilar. However, the packages doesn't seems to be published and I was wondering if there is any other alternatives in R.

Comment: Try emailing the presenter: mehmet (dot) balcilar (at) emu (dot) edu (dot) tr

Comment: I emailed the presenter at 3 different addresses, and had no response.  Maybe you'll have better luck? mehmet.balcilar(at)emu.edu.tr,
balcilar(at)kimep.kz,
mehmet(at)mbalcilar.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task view on time series mentions this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/index.html.